# How to add dynamic properties to TypesScript class and maintain correct typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a `Users` class that I am exporting from a file `Users.ts`

```js
    export default class Users {}
```

I am then exporting `Users.ts` from another file,  `index.ts`:

```js
    // classes
    export {default as Users} from './Users'
```

I have a third file, `Foo.ts`, where I want to dynamically instantiate all the exported classes from `index.ts` and add them as properties to that class:

```js
    import * as classes from './index'

    class Foo {
        constructor() {
           const httpClient = new HttpClient()
        }

        _addClasses() {
           for (const class in classes) {
             this[class] = new classes[class](this.httpClient);
           }
        }
    }
```

**My question is, how can I add the correct types to `Foo`, so that I can get the correct autocompletion in the IDE for `.users` like:**

```js
new Foo(new HttpClient).users
```

Comment: I don't see any definition for the property `.users` anywhere except for you attempting to use it.  And your `Foo` constructor doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: that's correct, I would like the type to be inferred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare dynamically added class properties in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038812/declare-dynamically-added-class-properties-in-typescript)

Comment: @Nit you are correct, but I was looking to avoid creating a wrapper function + type coercing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of this question is to create a new type that contains the instance types of the imported module. To do this, we will use the predefined conditional type `InstanceType` to extract the instance type of a class. To get the type of the module we will use `typeof classes`. Wrap it all in a mapped type and we get:

```
type ClassInstances = {
    [P in keyof typeof classes]: InstanceType<typeof classes[P]>
}

// For the example above this is equivalent to 
type ClassInstances = {
    Users: classes.Users;
}
```

Now we need to get these new properties into the class. To do this without defining them explicitly,  we can use an empty class expression as the base class for `Foo` and assert that the instance returned by this empty class has those members (it doesn't really, but we and these members in `_addClasses` so it all works out). Putting it all together we get:

```
import * as classes from './index';

type ClassInstances = {
    [P in keyof typeof classes]: InstanceType<typeof classes[P]>
}

class Foo extends (class {} as new () => ClassInstances) {
    httpClient: HttpClient;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.httpClient = new HttpClient()
        this._addClasses();
    }

    _addClasses() {
        for (const cls of Object.keys(classes) as Array<keyof typeof classes>) {
            this[cls] = new classes[cls](this.httpClient);
        }
    }
}

new Foo().Users // ok now name is the same as the name used in the export in index.ts so it's upper case. No string manipulation on string properties.
```