# How to create mapped type using generic class instances

Tags: typescript, class, generics, mapped-types

If I have a set of imported classes `classes`, I know I can create a type that maps the key name of the class, to the instance of that said class? For example:

Users.ts

```js
    export default class Users {}
```

index.ts

```js
    // classes
    export {default as Users} from './Users'
```

types.ts

```js
import * as classes from './index'

type ClassInstancesMapped = {
    [P in keyof typeof classes]: InstanceType<typeof classes[P]>
}

// For the example above this is equivalent to 
type ClassInstances = {
    Users: classes.Users;
}
```

(snippet borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177661/how-to-add-dynamic-properties-to-typesscript-class-and-maintain-correct-typings?noredirect=1&lq=1))

How can this be modified to include a generic parameter for each class instance? Specifically, how can I write a mapped type that emulates this:

```js
type ClassInstancesWithGeneric<T extends boolean> = {
    Users: classes.Users<T>;
}
```

I know the above (ClassInstancesWithGeneric) works properly, but when I try to modify ClassInstancesMapped to support the generic, nothing I can think of works. For example:

```js
// Do not work

type ClassInstancesMappedGeneric<T extends boolean> = {
    [P in keyof typeof classes]: InstanceType<classes[P]<T>>
}

type ClassInstancesMappedGeneric<T extends boolean> = {
    [P in keyof typeof classes]: InstanceType<classes[P]><T>
}

type ClassInstancesMappedGeneric<T extends boolean> = {
    [P in keyof typeof classes]: InstanceType<typeof (classes[P]<T>)>
}

type ClassInstancesMappedGeneric<T extends boolean> = {
    [P in keyof typeof classes]: classes[P]<T>
}
```

Any ideas?

**Update: June 2021**

This looks like it could only be accomplished using a 'higher kinded types' which are not official supported. The related Typescript [Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) goes into a few possible implementations, but its over 7 years old even with recent activity...

Comment: I don't think you can, you'd need to have something similar to `type GenericInstanceType<K, T extends AnyFunction<K>> = T extends new (...args: K[]) => infer R ? R<K> : never`, but the `infer` keyword doesn't have any way to specify generics.

Comment: Well that's frustrating haha. Ill keep digging and see if there is any other way beyond me explicitly listing them.